# How to realign a disk on logical volume with minimum to zero down time

Tags: linux, partition, disk, fdisk

A system running un-align disk partition that needs to be aligned without loss of data on all the partition including mbr with the minimum to no down time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new align partition

DISK=/dev/sdd  (assumed new disk is point to sdd)

```
  dd if=/dev/zero of=$DISK count=1 bs=1M
  parted -s -- $DISK mklabel msdos
  parted -s -- $DISK mkpart primary ext3 64s 401624s
  parted -s -- $DISK mkpart primary 401628s 6144866s
  parted -s -- $DISK mkpart primary 6144868s 100%
  parted $DISK unit s print

  (echo t; echo 1; echo 83;echo t; echo 2; echo 82;echo t; echo 3; echo 8e; echo w)  | fdisk $DISK
  (echo a; echo 1; echo w)  | fdisk $DISK
```

Install Grub:

```
  mkfs –t ext3 –L /boot dev/sdd1
  mount $DSIK1 /mnt
  cd /mnt 
  dump -0 -b 1024 -f - /boot/ | restore -r -f - -b 1024
  cd /
  umount /mnt
```

grub:

```
grub> device (hd1) /dev/sdd
device (hd1) /dev/sdd

grub>root (hd1,0)
     root (hd1,0)
     Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83

grub> setup (hd1)
    setup (hd1)
    Checking if "/boot/grub/stage1" exists... no
    Checking if "/grub/stage1" exists... yes
    Checking if "/grub/stage2" exists... yes
    Checking if "/grub/e2fs_stage1_5" exists... yes
    Running "embed /grub/e2fs_stage1_5 (hd1)"...  15 sectors are embedded.
    succeeded
    Running "install /grub/stage1 (hd1) (hd1)1+15 p (hd1,0)/grub/stage2  /grub/grub.conf"...

succeeded
    Done.

grub> quit
```

Adding new disk to LVM:

```
pvcreate  /dev/sdd3
```

Extend sdd to myvg lvm group:

```
    vgextend /dev/myvg /dev/sdd
```

Move Data to New Disk (Assumed old disk point to sda):

```
    pvmove –verbose /dev/sda3 /dev/sdd3
```

if there are other partition can be combined to a single partition:

```
    pvmove –verbose /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdd3
```

Remove Old LVM:

```
    vgreduce /dev/myvg /dev/sda3
    vgreduce /dev/myvg /dev/sda1
    pvremove /dev/sda1
    pvremove /dev/sda3
```

Please note that there is no immediate need to reboot the system. You may want to confirm reboot to make sure to boot up after removing unaligned disk.